# Bipartite graph with vertices with power law distribution

Tags: python, graph, networkx, bipartite, power-law

I need to create a network, which is a bipartite graph, and the degree of the vertices obeys power statistics. And then check if its true with

```
print(bipartite.is_bipartite(G))
```

In the bipartite.projected_graph() function, I substitute a random graph with a power-law distribution of degrees and a list of vertices. In this case, I do not get bipartite.

And if I insert a bipartite graph into this function and a data set obeying a power-law distribution, it always writes an error.

It's not entirely clear to me how a non-bipartite graph can be obtained using the bipartite.projected_graph() function.

I also tried to make a power-law distribution for vertices, but its randomly gives me True or False if I check if Grapgh is_bipartite.

```
from networkx.algorithms import bipartite
from networkx.generators.degree_seq import random_degree_sequence_graph
from networkx.algorithms.graphical import is_graphical
from networkx.utils.random_sequence import powerlaw_sequence
n, t = 10, 2
while True:  # Continue generating sequences until one of them is graphical
    seq = sorted([int(round(d)) for d in powerlaw_sequence(n, t)], reverse=True)  # Round to nearest integer to obtain DISCRETE degree sequence
    if is_graphical(seq):
        break
G_1 = random_degree_sequence_graph(seq, tries=100)  # Adjust number of tries as you see fit
print(sorted(d for _, d in G_1.degree()))
print(bipartite.is_bipartite(G_1))
degrees = dict(G_1.degree())
degree_distribution = {}
for d in degrees.values():
    if d in degree_distribution:
        degree_distribution[d] += 1
    else:
        degree_distribution[d] = 1


print(degree_distribution)
```

But also I tried make a hist of degree distribution

```
degrees = dict(G_1.degree())
degree_distribution = {}
for d in degrees.values():
    if d in degree_distribution:
        degree_distribution[d] += 1
    else:
        degree_distribution[d] = 1

x = np.array(list(degree_distribution.keys()))
y = np.array(list(degree_distribution.values()))

plt.loglog(x, y, 'ro')
plt.title('Степенное распределение')
plt.xlabel('Степень вершины')
plt.ylabel('Количество вершин')
plt.show()
```

[Degree distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40Ao9.png)

Moreover, I tried this code

```
import networkx as nx
import random


n = 100  # общее количество узлов
m = 4  # количество связей для новых узлов
p = 0.5  # вероятность присоединения к первой доле


G = nx.Graph()


G.add_nodes_from(range(n), bipartite=0)  # первая доля
G.add_nodes_from(range(n, 2*n), bipartite=1)  # вторая доля


for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n, 2*n):
        if random.random() < p:
            G.add_edge(i, j)


for i in range(2*n, n+m):
    
    targets = []
    for j in range(n):
        targets += [j] * G.degree(j)
    target = random.choice(targets)
    G.add_edge(i, target)

    
    targets = []
    for j in range(n, 2*n):
        targets += [j] * G.degree(j)
    target = random.choice(targets)
    G.add_edge(i, target)


print(nx.bipartite.is_bipartite(G))


degrees = dict(G.degree())
degree_distribution = {}
for d in degrees.values():
    if d in degree_distribution:
        degree_distribution[d] += 1
    else:
        degree_distribution[d] = 1
for d, count in degree_distribution.items():
    print(f"Degree {d}: {count} nodes")
```

And I got this

```
True
Degree 50: 18 nodes
Degree 54: 5 nodes
Degree 51: 20 nodes
Degree 46: 14 nodes
Degree 49: 17 nodes
Degree 56: 7 nodes
Degree 45: 14 nodes
Degree 40: 4 nodes
Degree 44: 9 nodes
Degree 48: 16 nodes
Degree 53: 11 nodes
Degree 47: 16 nodes
Degree 52: 11 nodes
Degree 61: 4 nodes
Degree 43: 7 nodes
Degree 57: 4 nodes
Degree 55: 9 nodes
Degree 59: 1 nodes
Degree 41: 4 nodes
Degree 42: 3 nodes
Degree 39: 3 nodes
Degree 58: 1 nodes
Degree 38: 1 nodes
Degree 62: 1 nodes
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you use `networkx`, call the function [`configuration_model`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.bipartite.generators.configuration_model.html#networkx.algorithms.bipartite.generators.configuration_model).